# assertRaisesRegexp does work with unicode in Python2

Tags: python, unit-testing, unicode

Hi I noticed assertRaisesRegexp doesn't work with unicode on Python 2.7.
I was trying the run the following code

```
import unittest
def raise_exception():
    raise Exception(u'\u4e2d\u6587')    

class TestUnicode(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_test1(self):
        with self.assertRaisesRegexp(Exception, u'\u4e2d\u6587'):
            raise_exception()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ZChenCode\unicode.py", line 27, in test_test1
  raise_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 127, in __exit__
    if not expected_regexp.search(str(exc_value)):
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Looks like Python standard library is trying to convert a unicode string to str type which caused the error.
This function works well on Python3 if I use assertRaiseRegx, no unicode issue.
Any suggestions on how to make it work in Python2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same issue here, unfortunately i can't fix it too, but i have a work arround for this, in my case i changed my raise Exception to this:

`raise Exception(u'\u4e2d\u6587'.encode('utf8'))`

this works for me here...

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach, which is make `str(exc_value)` work:

```
class UnicodeMsgException(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work better if you explicitly pass in a regexp object:

```
with self.assertRaisesRegexp(Exception, re.compile(u'\u4e2d\u6587')):
```

The documentation for assertRaisesRegexp suggests that you can just pass in a string as long as that can be used as a regexp, but at least for the python version I am using – 2.7.8 – that appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a new assertion method supporting Unicode:

```
    def assertRaisesRegexpUnicode(self, expected_exception, expected_regexp, callable_obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """Asserts that the message in a raised exception matches a regexp.

    Args:
        expected_exception: Exception class expected to be raised.
        expected_regexp: Regexp (re pattern object or string) expected
                to be found in error message.
        callable_obj: Function to be called.
        args: Extra args.
        kwargs: Extra kwargs.
    """
    if callable_obj is None:
        return _AssertRaisesContext(expected_exception, self, expected_regexp)
    try:
        callable_obj(*args, **kwargs)
    except expected_exception, exc_value:
        if isinstance(expected_regexp, basestring):
            expected_regexp = re.compile(expected_regexp)
        actual = exc_value.message
        if not expected_regexp.search(actual):
            raise self.failureException(u'"{expected}" does not match "{actual}"'.
                format(expected=expected_regexp.pattern, actual=actual))
    else:
        if hasattr(expected_exception, '__name__'):
            excName = expected_exception.__name__
        else:
            excName = str(expected_exception)
        raise self.failureException, "%s not raised" % excName
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewriting `assertRaisesRegex` like suggested by mtoloo, you can also monkeypatch `unittest2.case.str` like so:

```
# unittest2's assertRaisesRegex doesn't do unicode comparison.
# Let's monkeypatch the str() function to point to unicode()
# so that it does :)
# For reference, this is where this patch is required: 
# https://hg.python.org/unittest2/file/tip/unittest2/case.py#l227
try:
    unittest2.case.str = unicode
except Exception:
    pass # python 3
```